# WordPress site front page fails to load in IE

Tags: frontpage, apache, dns

*Disclaimer: I'm a front-end guy dabbling in back-end work.*

I have WordPress serving up a company Intranet site on a CentOS VM in a multiple vhost setup (LAMP). It resides at `http://intranet.domain.com/` and is only accessible inside our network.

The site has been working well in Chrome and Firefox, but for some reason, the front page fails to load in IE for a few users. They can get to other parts of the site (i.e. `http://intranet.domain.com/news/`) by appending the path to the URL... and those pages load just fine. Up until today, it's only affected a few other people in our company. Today, it's finally showing itself on my machine - so I can **finally debug it!**

### DNS Config at the moment

[DNS Config shot](https://cloudup.com/c1SU9a0hzXz)

1. Using Windows Server 2008 DNS.
2. Research led me to create a new Forward Lookup Zone called `intranet.domain.com`.
3. I was directed to create an unnamed A record that pointed to the the IP of the CentOS box.

### Apache vhost config

[Intranet vhost config shot](https://cloudup.com/cEYADLjS4b1)

### Troubleshooting

**IE 11, Win 7 x64.**

1. Open IE w/ `http://intranet.domain.com` set as homepage. Fails to resolve.
2. Refresh. Still nothing.
3. Append `/news/` to URL and the page loads without issue.
4. Click home link. Fails to resolve.
5. Pings to `intranet.domain.com` return from proper internal IP: 192.168.50.89.
6. Test in Chrome & Canary... `intranet.domain.com` **Loads w/o issue**.
7. Test in Firefox & Aurora... `intranet.domain.com` **Loads w/o issue**.
8. Test `http://capsule.domain.com` in IE (setup the same way intranet is in DNS)... loads w/o issue.
9. Notice that it redirects to `http://capsule/wp-admin/`...
10. Test `http://intranet/` in IE. Loads!
11. Close IE, open IE (`intranet.domain.com` still set as Home)... Fails.
12. Config IE to open `http://intranet/` and `http://intranet.domain.com/` in two tabs at startup.
13. Close IE, open IE ... FQDN tab fails. `http://intranet/` LOADS.

### What gives?

Anyone encountered anything like this?

---

#### Update (3/5)

Looks like opening the site in IE's **InPrivate** mode at the fqdn works. Then, closing IE and reopening it normal mode and all is well.

Stumped as to why this is... but that *workaround* has gotten the affected users into the site successfully.

Comment: If it "fails to resolve" looks like a DNS issue or a server issue, but not a WP issue. You might find better help at stackoverflow or at one of the other stackexchange websites (such as web master).